# driver.quit() after unhandled exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Python script that I'm using to keep another Python script running on a loop.

I basically call it like this `python loop.py script.py`

The `script.py` uses selenium and chromedriver to perform whatever it needs to do, I'm trying to keep this script running 24/7, so whenever it fails, the loop script just restarts it and opens another instance of the chromedriver, opening another chrome window.

My problem is that whenever I keep this script running for several hours, there's a point where I have too many chrome windows opened, causing the computer to go crazy slow as you would expect.

`script.py` is divided into multiple functions, with one function calling some of the other functions like:

```
def caller_function():
  function1()
  function2()
  function3()
  function4()
```

I already have some of the exceptions handled so basically the scripts only stops whenever an unhandled exception occurs.

This unhandled exception can happen in any of the functions so I can't seem to find a way around handling(?) the unhandled exception to make it do a `driver.quit()` so it closes the instance that failed before the `loop.py` calls `script.py` again and opens another chrome window.

I tried doing:

```
def caller_function():
 try:
   function1()
   function2()
   function3()
   function4()
 except:
   driver.quit()
```

But it didn't work, as for some reason the driver.quit() fell into a loop and stopped `loop.py` from restarting `script.py`

Basically, I'm trying not to have 20+ chrome windows open whenever I wake up in the morning to check the progress of the script. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: please add how are you runnign this in loop add the full code

Comment: you have only one "driver"  then how it opens multiple tab

Comment: It's only one driver, it opens multiple chrome instances because it restarts the program every time it stops for an unhandled exception.

Comment: the loop is basically `while True: p = Popen("python ./script.py", shell=True) p.wait()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use finally for that purpose:

```
 try:
   # your code

 finally:
   driver.quit()
```

Comment: I will try this, my only concern is if it will work even if the exception occurs in one of the functions that are being called by the other one?

Comment: @rekeson21 work each time independently from actual result, like final step, you can use driver like context manager as well, like with driver: and everything in that construction

Comment: so, it works in the way that it closes the driver after an exception. But it is closing too after a handled exception, which is not suitable for what I'm looking for. I have several handled exceptions in the script that are part of the functionality of it. The script relies on those.

Comment: I just found a way to make this work, the solution was right but my implementation was wrong.